# read first line of netstat output?

Tags: bash, tcp, cygwin, netstat

I want to read only the  first line of netstat, i.e. the line that explains  what each column means:

```
Proto  Local Address     Foreign Address  State
```

However, when I do the following:

```
netstat | egrep -i "^\s*(tcp|udp)" | { 
  read line
  echo 'Here is the first line ' $line
 }
```

I only get the first line of connections:

```
Here is the first line TCP <Local_addr>  <Foreign_addre>  ESTABLISHED
```

How do I get just that one line?

I am runing Cygwin on Windows 7 machine.  Thanks.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `read` for this purpose - I'd find a way to pull out just that one line and assign it directly to a variable. Example: `line="$(netstat -n | sed -n 2p)"`

Answer (score 1):

To read the first output line of any command, such as `netstat`, into the shell variable `line`, use:

```
read -r line < <(netstat| head -n1)
```

The use `head` is not necessary here but it speeds things up.

A side-effect of the above is that any leading or trailing whitespace is removed before the line is assigned to `line`.  That is probably an advantage here.  If you wanted to preserve the whitespace, use `IFS= read -r line < <(netstat| head -n1)`.

The construct `< <(...)` is called process substitution.  It requires bash or other advanced shell.  Note that the space between the two `<` is essential.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good explanation.  Nothing is placed into "line" when I run this, though. It prints out nothing.

Comment: @Sother Does `netstat | head -n1` run by itself produce any output?

Comment: `netstat | head -nX`, where X is any positive integer, properly prints out the appropriate line.  However,  I am unable to retrieve it via `echo` when run in a bash script.

Comment: This works. However, my netstat outputs in the 1st line `Active Internet connections`, so get the `nTH` line i would to use: `netstat | sed -n 2p` (e.g. for the second line - what contais: `Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)`

Comment: @Sother At the command line, please run `read -r line < <(netstat| head -n1); echo "line=$line"` and tell me what you see.

Comment: I see `line=`  which is interesting.